# Does Send endpoint waits for the consumer to complete?

Tags: masstransit

I am starting with MassTransit and I have notice that when I call `Send<T>` in the `ISendEndpoint` it seems that the caller waits for the consumer to complete, is it an expected behavior? Since I am not using the mediator, shouldn't it just send the message to the endpoint and let the API (from which I am calling) free to process other requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Send` on a bus send endpoint does not wait for the consumer to complete. The returned `Task` is completed once the message has been acknowledged by the broker.

If you are using the request client, and calling `GetResponse`, that will wait for a response before completing the returned `Task<TResponse>`.

> Using mediator, `Send` does wait.

Comment: In order to use the Bus should I inject IBus or ISendEndpoitProvider? Using the IBus, I could see the expected behavior but it took 23s to the RabbitMq to ack the message. I basically take a long time debugging the consumer to see that

Comment: Well, I believe it takes too long because I was holding the threads during my debug session...